# undefined reference, compilation error

Tags: c++, reference, undefined

I am trying to use class inheritance. I have taken a code from a book and tweaked it a bit to create Class Mammal and a Class Dog which inherits Mammal member data. The code is:

```
#include<iostream>

enum BREED{Labrador,Alcetian,Bull,Dalmetian,Pomerarian};


class Mammal{

 public:
    Mammal();
    ~Mammal(){}
    double getAge(){return age;}
    void setAge(int newAge){age=newAge;}
    double getWeight(){return weight;}
    void setWeight(double newWeight){weight=newWeight;}
    void speak(){std::cout<<"Mammal sound!\n";}
 protected:
    int age;
    double weight;

};

class Dog : public Mammal{

 public:
    Dog();
    ~Dog(){}
    void setBreed(BREED newType){type=newType;}
    BREED getBreed(){return type;}
 private:
    BREED type;
};

int main(){
 Dog Figo;

 Figo.setAge(2);
 Figo.setBreed(Alcetian);
 Figo.setWeight(2.5);
 std::cout<<"Figo is a "<<Figo.getBreed()<<" dog\n";
 std::cout<<"Figo is "<<Figo.getAge()<<" years old\n";
 std::cout<<"Figo's weight is "<<Figo.getWeight()<<" kg\n";
 Figo.speak();

 return 0; 
}
```

When I run this code,, it gives me the following error:

C:\cygwin\tmp\cc7m2RsP.o:prog3.cpp:(.text+0x16): undefined reference to `Dog::Dog()'
collect2.exe: error: ld returned 1 exit status

Any help would be appreciated. Thanks.

Comment: most methods in both classes are only DECLARATION, (i.e. have not body). Somewhere must be implemented (in C++ : defined)

Comment: You're missing parenthesis (Dog() { } )

Comment: Generic wisecrack: If the toolchain complains about X (here: "undefined"), that X *is* usually the reason why it complains. ;-) `Dog::Dog()` isn't defined.

Comment: Such a stupid mistake to forget defining the constructor. Thanks everyone for replying.

Answer (score 1):

You didn't define constructors, you only declared them:

```
class Mammal{
public:
    Mammal();  // <-- declaration

...

class Dog : public Mammal{
public:
    Dog();  // <-- declaration
```

When you declare a constructor (or any function) then the C++ compiler will look for the constructor's definition elsewhere. And when it can't find it it complains. For basic definitions try this:

```
class Mammal{
public:
    Mammal() {};  // <-- definition

...

class Dog : public Mammal{
public:
    Dog() {};  // <-- definition
```

You can also remove them entirely since they don't seem to do anything (C++ will insert default constructor for you).

Answer (score 0):

This because you have just declared the non-parameterized constructors `Dog();` and `Mammal();` in respective classes, but not defined it.

To remove the error do following:

- In `class Mammal`,  change line `Mammal();` to `Mammal(){}` **AND**
- In `class Dog`, change line `Dog();` to `Dog() {}`.

Answer (score 0):

You have declared constructor for the class `Dog::Dog();`, its not defined. Means constructor is missing body. Define a constructor as follows

`public:
    Dog::Dog(){ 
       //statements
    }`