# calling a parameter from the constructor in c++

Tags: c++

I am trying to use something that in the constructor but I get compile error
here is the constructor

```
Matrix::Matrix(int rows, int cols, std::string matType) {
type = matType;
row = rows;
col = cols;
array= new double*[row];
for (int i = 0; i < row; ++i)
    array[i] = new double[col];
for (int i = 0; i < rows; i++)
    for (int j = 0; j<cols; j++)
        array[i][j] = 0;}
```

Here is the implimintation of the function

```
void Matrix::setElement(int i, int j, double data) {
if (i > row || j > col)
    return;

if (strcmp(type, "Any") == 0) {//here is the problem i cant use type i get compile error
    array[i][j] = data;
}
if (strcmp(type, "Arrowhead") == 0) {
    if (data != 0 && i == 0) {
        array[i][j] = data;
    }
    if (data != 0 && j == 0)
        array[i][j] = data; {
    }
    if (data != 0 && j == i) {
        array[i][j] = data;
    }
} }
```

And here is the header(my class)

```
 class Matrix {
public:
string type;
int row, col;
double **array;

public:
Matrix(int rows, int cols, std::string matType);    // set the (i,j) element to be 'data'
void setElement(int i, int j, double data); // return the (i,j) element
```

The problem is here

```
if (strcmp(type, "Any") == 0)
```

Ia m new to C++ and I don't get whats the problem I get no suitable conversion function from `std::string` to `const char *` exists

Comment: `strcmp()` is for `char[]`, just use `==` for `std::string`

Comment: Try this if (strcmp(type.c_str(), "Any") == 0) but using == as Arun explained is better.

Comment: @dsp_user - The answer section is bellow. You should post this anti-pattern there, where it may be rightfully down-voted.

Comment: He mentioned the conversion function so that's what I gave him. Anyway, this is simple enough for a comment.

Comment: @dsp_user - It's an attempt at an answer. And it's an awful answer. Which I surmise you understand, otherwise you would not attempt to bypass the peer review mechanism.

Comment: That's just stupid. If something is simple, then I will usually try to answer in a comment (like here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47752165/undefined-reference-compilation-error#comment82464734_47752165 ).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A `std::string` is not a `const char*`. It cannot be implicitly converted to one, and you can't pass it to `strcmp` as if it were. But you don't need to. `std::string` is sane type, and you can just compare directly:

```
if (type == "Any") {
}
```

For a situation where you *do need* a "C-string" view of a `std::string`, it has a member function named `c_str()` that returns such a pointer. But again, comparison is not such a situation.

Answer (score 3):

[hint] if you're new to C++,

- try to not use pointers, anywhere
- try to use a library instead of implementing matrix ([`eigen`](https://eigen.tuxfamily.org/dox/GettingStarted.html) is a good one)
- do read up on how bad it can get if your code contains `new`, and how you can benefit from using `std::vector` instead

This small investment will save you tons of headaches in the (near) future.

Comment: I understand that you're giving advice which is good and all, but do add the answer to the question as well along with it

Comment: Sometimes, the question hides the true need of the OP :).  His current need seems to be to avoid overly complex matter.  I wish people had steered _me_ away from writing code for stuff that existed.  Heck - the sheer number of matrix implementations I've seen...